# Mysql query returns undefined node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using a database cluster from Digital Ocean and I am trying to make an query request from my node.js api

this is the code I am using

```
app.get('/current', (req, res) => {
// THIS GETS THE INFORMATION IF YOU WANT DIFFERENT INFO CHANGE THE SQL QUERY
const SQL = "SELECT * FROM ParkingLot;"
db.query(SQL,(err, result) =>{
    console.log(result)
    res.send(result);
})
})
```

in the console log it prints undefined. I know I have values in the database. I am just running out of ideas about what to do. I have tried using async to solve the problem but I'm not sure that I am either using it correctly or what.

this is one of the solutions i have tried

```
app.get('/current', async (req, res) => {
// THIS GETS THE INFORMATION IF YOU WANT DIFFERENT INFO CHANGE THE SQL QUERY
const result = await numFullSpaces();
res.send(result)
console.log(numFullSpaces());

})

function numFullSpaces(){
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM ParkingLot;"
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                rej(err);
            }else{
                res(result)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

from this I get the error

triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

I am at a loss as to what I should do next.

Comment: In the first snippet you are not doing anything with `err`. But you got the timedout error in the second. I would guess that the issue is that your connection settings are wrong.

Comment: and what if the sql said "drop ParkingLot"? how are you protecting against sql injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly concatenating user input into the SQL query, use parameterized queries with placeholders. This will prevent SQL injection attacks by automatically escaping user input.

```
const SQL = "SELECT * FROM ParkingLot WHERE id = ?";
db.query(SQL, [req.params.id], (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  } else {
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  }
});
```

Plus: the err parameter is checked. If there is an error, it is logged to the console and a 500 Internal Server Error response is sent to the client. If there is no error, the result is logged to the console and sent to the client.